# How to connect WordPress media to another host?

Tags: plugins, uploads, hosting

I have uploaded about 1000 PDF files in the media section of the WordPress site, how can I transfer the files to another host and change the links of the files in the content of the site?

the second question, is there a plugin or a method that only files with a specific format, for example, PDF, can be uploaded to another host when uploaded in WordPress, and the images remain on the main host?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to migrate the site to another host? In that case, any migration plugin will do it with ease.

Comment: No, instead of directly uploading large files such as videos and PDFs on my site, I want to upload them on another host and put their links in my site posts.